# How to change the text parsed from PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, css

I managed to parse text from another website using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. The text I managed to parse is all in HTML's `<p>...</p>` which looks similar like this on the

Source website as:  **Telephone Number:** 123456789

but is looking on my website as:  Telephone Number: 123456789.

I would like the words 'Telephone Number' and similar words to be bold (like in the source website) or in a different color than the CSS colour of my website. Can this be done?

I need this to copy the details off various HTML pages of my Church's website of my country's parishes in my country. I already obtained permission to use the information.

I tried to google it but didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Of the parsed text you mean? The source website is http://maltadiocese.org/lang/en/parishes/attard/ for example... and the source's html code is for the information I need is as follows _<h3><span lang="en">Telephone</span></h3> 
<p><span lang="en">21434949</span></p>_

Comment: Yes. It seems like you are already parsing and outputting something. It would help to know what exactly you are doing :)

Comment: The php part. You are parsing the text and then what are you doing to create the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the exact string you want to replace you can use str_replace

```
$string = '<p>This is my super dupa text and it has my phone number: 083 23212212 32</p>';
$string = str_replace("phone number:", "<b>phone number:</b>", $string);
```

String now has 'phone number:' in bold. If you have a number of things to replace you can use str_replace with arrays. look at the examples on the php website here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I'll give it a try :-) Seems like what I was looking for. Excellent and thank you :-)