# How to change certain words that have been parsed from another website?

Tags: php, html, css

How to change certain words that have been parsed from another website?

I parsed text from a third party website using this PHP code:

```
<?php
 include_once 'externalcode/simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(10);
/* update your path accordingly */
$url  ='http://maltadiocese.org/lang/en/parishes/attard/';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('Information about this Parish is currently unavailable');
foreach($html->find('span[lang=en]') as $webLink){
    echo $webLink->plaintext.'<br>';
    echo $webLink->href.'<br>';
} 
foreach($html->find('div[id=textwidget]') as $Link2){
    echo $webLink2->plaintext.'<div style="display:none";>';    
}    
?>
```

I successfully managed to parse the text. Now I would like to change the style of specific words of certain in the parsed text i.e. say Parish Church of the Assumption, it is parsed on my website as plain text. I'd like to make it bold, red and say underlined.

I followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648709/how-to-change-the-text-parsed-from-php-simple-html-dom-parser) but it didn't work for me.

My intention is to parse text and change it to abide by CSS rules.

Thanks

Comment: i can't recommend javascript highly enough

Comment: I was thinking more of using PHP such as regex or str_replace

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom classes on your CSS to give the desired effect (let's call the HTML class `foo`). Then, in the code, you'd do the following:

```
<?php
$textToFind = 'Parish Church of the Assumption';
$replace    = '<span class="foo">' . $textToFind . '</span>';
str_replace($textToFind, $replace, $parsedText);
```

Then, on the css stylesheet, you'd do:

```
.foo {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**EDIT:** Sample of the full code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .foo {
                text-decoration: underline;
                color: red;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $parsedText = fetch_text();
    $textToFind = 'Parish Church of the Assumption';
    $replace    = '<span class="foo">' . $textToFind . '</span>';
    echo str_replace($textToFind, $replace, $parsedText);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Basically that the .foo isn't working. Its not changing any formats or anything. It is remaining as it was. Though the problem is in the PHP rather than in the CSS.

Comment: I placed it in the CSS and the PHP in the php page itself.